# Bash - date, working around the 2038 bug on 32bit LINUX system

Tags: linux, date, gnu

I wrote a little bash script that made me stumble across the ["Year 2038 Bug"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). I did not know about this problem before and I just dare on posting the `--debug` output I got from `date` when my script tried to calculate across this magic date (03:14:07 UTC on 19 January 2038).

**`date -d "20380119"`**

```
date: parsed number part: today/this/now
date: input timezone: +01:00 (set from system default)
date: warning: using midnight as starting time: 00:00:00
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2038-01-19 00:00:00 TZ=+01:00'
date: '(Y-M-D) 2038-01-19 00:00:00 TZ=+01:00' = 2147468400 epoch-seconds
date: output timezone: +01:00 (set from system default)
date: final: 2147468400.000000000 (epoch-seconds)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2038-01-18 23:00:00 (UTC0)
date: final: (Y-M-D) 2038-01-19 00:00:00 (output timezone TZ=+01:00)
Tue Jan 19 00:00:00 CET 2038
```

**`date -d "20380119 + 1 days"`**

```
date: parsed hybrid part: +1 day(s)
date: input timezone: +01:00 (set from system default)
date: warning: using midnight as starting time: 00:00:00
date: starting date/time: '(Y-M-D) 2038-01-19 00:00:00 TZ=+01:00'
date: warning: when adding relative days, it is recommended to specify 12:00pm
date: error: adding relative date resulted in an invalid date: '(Y-M-D) 2038-01-20 00:00:00 TZ=+01:00'
date: invalid date '20380119 + 1 days'
```

**`date -d "20380120" --debug`**

```
date: parsed number part: today/this/now
date: input timezone: +01:00 (set from system default)
date: warning: using midnight as starting time: 00:00:00
date: error: invalid date/time value:
date:     user provided time: '(Y-M-D) 2038-01-20 00:00:00 TZ=+01:00'
date:        normalized time: '(Y-M-D) 2038-01-20 00:00:00 TZ=+01:00'
date: 
date:      possible reasons:
date:        numeric values overflow;
date:        missing timezone
date: invalid date '20380120'
```

**Is there any way to make GNU `date` calculate across this date?**
(on a LINUX 32 bit system)

```
  Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux buster/sid
            Kernel: Linux 4.12.0-2-686-pae
      Architecture: x86
```

Comment: One way to get around it in 32 bit systems is using a *BSD OS.

Comment: Not bash but: http://search.cpan.org/~mschwern/Time-y2038-20100403/lib/Time/y2038.pm

Comment: @Kusalananda sorry for being unclear. Yes I'm asking about a way for GNU `date`. I'll edit my question...

Comment: FWIW, OpenBSD [fixed that in 2014](http://www.openbsd.org/55.html).  It was a lot work, but somehow they managed to patch all the relevant bits.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Not exactly true: [time_t is 8 bytes on all supported architectures except i386](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=arch&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12-current&arch=default&format=html).

Comment: Interesting enough, many filesystem routines on 64 bit Linux had problems with dates in the future, until recently. Read an article where the kernel had some fixes for that.  On my servers, `touch -t 252512310102.03 y2038.txt` yields a date of `Jan 19  2038`

Comment: @MarkStewart on my 32 bit system I get: `touch: invalid date format '252512310102.03'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to stick to GNU `date` on 32-bit Linux, there’s no easy way to get it to work with dates after 2038. [The `coreutils` maintainers don’t consider this a `coreutils` bug](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2009-02/msg00144.html), so don’t expect a fix there — the fix will have to come from [the C library](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Y2038ProofnessDesign) and the kernel. If you want to play around with the work in progress, you’ll need:

- [Arnd Bergmann’s kernel patches](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/arnd/playground.git/log/?h=y2038) (most of which are merged or close to being merged, as of version 5.1 of the kernel),
- [Albert Aribaud’s `glibc` patches](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=shortlog;h=refs/heads/aaribaud/y2038) (based on [the design outlined here](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/Y2038ProofnessDesign)),

and a decent amount of skill and patience.

For more on the way 2038 was planned to be handled in the 32-bit Linux world, see [LWN](https://old.lwn.net/Articles/717076/) and [the write-up of the 2038 BoF at DebConf 17](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2017/09/msg00035.html) (with the follow-up comments there and [on LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/732794/)). [This January 2019 LWN article](https://lwn.net/Articles/776435/) describes the changes which are being implemented in the kernel.