# On which systems does the time() function act as a system call?

Tags: posix, time

According to the [POSIX.1-2008 standards](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html), `time()` is implemented as a system call in some systems.

In which systems would this be the case?

My concern is that, when `time()` is a system call, all dates past January 17, 2038 would return a large negative integer, which could break some programs.

Comment: I don't see why it matters whether `time()` is implemented as a system call or a library function.

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396447/117549

Comment: This is a tough question for this StackExchange format, as the Answer could change over time.

Answer (score 4):

Only on systems that remain on a 32-bit integer, which is neither mandated by POSIX 2008 nor a universal practice. [OpenBSD went to a 64-bit `time_t` in 2013](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&m=137637321205010&w=2). However! Individual applications will need to be audited to see if they use a 32-bit epoch, so it is necessary but not sufficient for an OS to simply use a larger integer type.

As Johan Myréen points out, whether `time` is a system call or something else is irrelevant to the 2038 problem: supported systems (and the applications that run on them) will be fixed, and unsupported systems (and applications) won't.